# Can I add a third hard drive to my PC?

Tags: hard-drive

I have a Dell Precision Tower 3620. It came with accessories that let me mount a single hard drive, but recently I decided to buy a second so that I could link them with SATA 1 to provide a bit of a backup. When I got my new drive, I opened my computer to find that while there was a bay there for a second hard drive, there was no drive holder or data cable for a second drive.

My computer is currently configured with one SSD drive for C: and a Seagate Baracuda hard drive for D:. If I want to add another hard drive, is it as simple as buying an extra drive bay holder and data cable, or is my computer incapable of doing this?

Comment: Can you take some pictures of the inside?   Really, the most important thing is to check if there are additional SATA ports on the motherboard (which there most likely are), and then power - but even if you don't have a power connector, you can always buy a Y connector.  I would expect that a tower system would be able to take more drives.

Answer (score 3):

The specs for your machine: https://i.dell.com/sites/csdocuments/Shared-Content_data-Sheets_Documents/en/us/Dell_Precision_Tower3620.pdf

It looks like you get one motherboard SSD and you have four SATA ports available but you are limited to two 3.5" drives for physical reasons.

The most critical resource is SATA ports.  If they're all full the only way to add a drive is with an expansion card.  Data cables are routine items that are easy to buy.  Likewise, power connectors are standard--if you're out of connectors you get a Y cable.

Answer (score 0):

Your motherboard has 4 SATA ports - https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/04/precision-t3620-workstation/prec_t3620_om_pub/specifications?guid=guid-0a90134e-599f-4abc-b76b-4bbf7c540321&lang=en-us links to a PDF that shows where they are on page 23.

I think one of those ports may be a slower SATA connection for a DVD.